# How can I trigger some functions when user is doing something in the textfield in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to display the password validator popup as users type their passwords. I tried to do with onFocus or onClick, however, it seems like it triggers just once. Is there any attribute to determine if a user clicks certain input and stays in that field?

I'd tried to do with hooks, however, I am stuck on how to reset the value when use is off the password input to take off the popup. Like the picture below, the popup will only stay open when the user is typing in that field.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onChangeText` function to capture the events while user is typing in textbox. You can use `onBlur` event of textbox which is fired when user moves out of the textbox

```
                <TextInput
                   
                    onChangeText={(text) => { 
                                // Display the popup here 
                    }}
                    onBlur={() => { 
                                // Remove the popup here  
                     }}
                />
```